Why does the Music app, YouTube videos, VLC Media all start/pause randomly in macOS?
This happens on macOS 15.2 (started even on 15.0):

Apple Music opens and plays a song (randomly). Had to install NoTunes to stop this.
IfI am watching a video either a) YouTube (in a browser) or b) VLC Media Player - these videos will pause/play/pause/play without any interference from my side, ie keyboard buttons etc.

Tried a lot of search on this. On (1) only answer was NoTunes. The item (2) is tough to search for… still looking.
My system.log keeps logging:
Dec 26 08:36:44 MyMac AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[509]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:24
Dec 26 08:36:49 MyMac AMPDevicesAgent[791]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:25
Dec 26 08:36:49 MyMac AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[509]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:25
Dec 26 08:36:49 MyMac AMPDevicesAgent[791]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:25
Dec 26 08:36:49 MyMac AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[509]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:25
Dec 26 08:37:06 MyMac AMPDevicesAgent[791]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:26
Dec 26 08:37:06 MyMac AMPDevicesAgent[791]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:26
Dec 26 08:37:06 MyMac AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[509]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:26
Dec 26 08:37:06 MyMac AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[509]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:26
Dec 26 08:47:09 MyMac syslogd[160]: ASL Sender Statistics


Few things to add....

Macbook Pro 2018 with TouchBar
The behavior is equivalent to clicking play/pause on the keyboard or touchbar.
i tried disabling, killing, touchbar etc
Turning off BlueTooth, Handoff, etc.
and all the many things google search offered to stop the Apple Music from launching


Welcome to Superuser. Your question is unclear. First, if you have anything to add, use the EDIT button to add it to your question and do not add it down here in comments. Second, are you WANTING to open Apple Music, or it is opening when you have NOT asked it to, and playing and pausing. Third, I'm not experienced reading Apple error logs, but that looks like something is connecting and disconnecting from your laptop. Check for any loose connections, gently shake the laptop, press firmly around its body to see if you can trigger this behavior to indicate a connection fault.
